# Realloc 2D array

Tags: c

I'm starting to learn C and would like input characters from a command line and sort them into an array such that the row number is the ASCII character number and the columns are the index of the character from the input. I know that this must be dynamically done via realloc and malloc but I wouldn't know how to code it up. Could someone help me with this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define totalASCII     256
int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
int locat;
char current;
int **dRow=NULL;

dRow = malloc(totalASCII*sizeof(*dRow));


for(locat=0;scanf("%c", &current)==1;locat++)   {
    /* I don't know what to put here */
    }
return 1;
}
```

Comment: **dRow is pointer to a pointer and not a pointer to an array so allocating a memory and accessing it will lead to segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

Your data is so small, there's really no need to allocate it from the heap. Just use an array:

```
struct { char character; int input_index; } input_data[totalASCII];
```

On a typical 32-bit system, this will use about 256 * 8 or 2 KB of memory, which really isn't all that much.

Then the storing would be:

```
for(locat = 0; scanf("%c", &current) == 1; locat++)
{
  input_data[locat].character = current;
  input_data[locat].input_index = locat;
}
```

Comment: How about indexing of the characters in the columns?

Comment: how would it store when same character is given multiple times?

Comment: Move along the row to the next empty column

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: haven't compiled and run the code.

Try something like this:

```
int prev_size = 1;

dRow = calloc(totalASCII, sizeof(*dRow)); //use calloc

for(locat=0;scanf("%c", &current)==1;locat++)   {
    if(dRow[current]) {
       prev_size=0;
       //try to find how much is already allocated
       while(dRow[current][prev_size] != -1) 
           prev_size++;

       dRow[current] = realloc(sizeof(int) * (prev_size+1));
     }
    else {
       prev_size = 1;
       dRow[current] = malloc(sizeof(int) * (prev_size+1));
    }
    dRow[current][prev_size-1] = locat;
    dRow[current][prev_size-1] = -1;   //end identifier  

}
```

The complexity here is to find the previous allocated size. As there is no other structure/data structure to store this info, this sample code tries to iterate over the array and find `-1` which is assumed as end marker.